Wavy edge siding - single board replacement
new homeowner here.
My house has live edge cedar siding installed. It looks great, but one of the boards has deteriorated and needs replaced. I have experience in exterior remodeling but have never replaced one of these.
If the board needing replaced is in the middle of the wall, will I need to remove all the boards above? Or below? Is there a video / manual I can watch? I watched how to get those installed, but that's not what I need.
Thanks in advance

Live edge cedar siding looks generally like regular wood or strip siding. There are google-able videos on replacing a strip of such siding. Try applying the general siding tips to your particular situation, it'll probably be the same.

Replacing your siding should be the same as replacing any other wood siding. I typically use a thin pry bar to start easing the damaged siding up off the lower course that below the damaged piece, to test how the nails will remove. if you mess up learning on the damaged piece, no harm. You do not want to learn the hard way on the siding you want to save.
You could just rip it out, but then you wouldn't learn how the upper course above the damaged siding is going to release.  When lifting the edge, DO NOT pull on the bar, if anything, only push on it, making sure the tip of the bar is touching or stradling the nail that is holding in that spot. Either the nail will draw through the wood and stay in the framing/sheathing, or it will pull with the siding. If you pull on the bar, it is very prone to crack the siding. If the nail does release with the board, remove the bar and expose the nail head by tapping back the siding only, so the nail stays out, so it can be pulled without damaging the siding.
The only direct pressure that is used on the bottom edge of the siding, should only be a the place where the nails are. In some cases, I have had to start between the nails to get a gap started, to "walk" the pry bars down to the nails. It will be good to have more than one bar for this.
If you use this piece for practice, you will have less chance of damaging the piece or pieces that will stay, otherwise you can chase this problem all the way up the wall.
If the place that you test is rotted, then it will pull through, so try this where the siding is still good.
After you test the bad piece a few times, no need to do the whole run, apply what you learn to the piece that is good, for the nails that hold the bottom of the next piece up, is also driven through the top of the next piece down, typically. There are cases they are not. if so, then the siding will readily drop out when the bottom of the rotted piece is freed.
Once all the nails are removed, or perhaps not, since some may insist on staying, then the bad piece of siding can be removed, after it is cleared of nails, and after the top if it is released, what damage happens to it then is of no concern, except for what makes it easier to remove. Pull straight down on the bad piece, and with some coaxing it should pull from under the upper piece. If nails are left in at the top, it may split and leave a piece of the damaged siding under the upper piece of siding. That will make it difficult to place the new piece.
Any piece that may remain, will need to be carefully removed, then with that space opened up, the siding can be moved in, to expose that nail head to finish making the room for the new piece.
